# PSD to XHTML/CSS Conversion

Tags: html, css, xhtml, photoshop, psd

If I have a psd and trying to figure out what is the best diminsions to use for the html conversion what would be best. Just do the psd image size?

I have my site and the page to what my image should look like below.

Website: http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com

Mockup jpg: http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/images/wrestling.jpg

I went to psd2htmlconverter.com paid 3 bucks and got something but the html and css shows correctly but its not separated like it should be.

http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/crap/admintemp/testing/index.html

But I'm really trying to work off of the main website css.

Comment: If your PSD is 1x1 pixels, your approach might prove to be a problem....

Comment: Well it was a design that I paid someone to create. I was just trying to get more experience converting.

Comment: I do not know if I understood you well, but usually PSD is made with specific grid in mind. So you should already have some dimensions predefined. If you have completely random size in PSD than it might be tough to calculate all dimensions correctly.

Comment: This is too broad of a question. What is your goal? What type of user do you want to support? Is 1024x768 likely to be the lowest resolution you need to support? Mobile users? How large is this psd? I have no idea what you might need to build, really. Are you asking this because you're hiring a cheap psd to xhtml service? If that's the case, don't ask us - Ask the people you're hiring.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's best for _your_ target audience?

Comment: Its not a cheap design. I had a good company design me something very nice I think. Just with the design not sure the BEST way to go about coding the xhtml/css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you're talking about how to slice the PSD, I wouldn't slice everything at set dimensions. Let the layout dictate where to slice, and try to slice it logically by section, in such a way that reassembling it with HTML/CSS is easy.

Start by mentally diving the layout into sections, e.g. top banner, left column, right column, content area, footer, etc. After sectioning the layout, just start slicing it logically into small or medium sized images.

It might help to create a skeleton in HTML/CSS so you have an idea of how you need to slice the template. This tends to work out well because you're not just slicing it randomly, but rather you're slicing it to fit the skeleton that you created. Obviously, you may need to slice a big image like a top banner into a few parts, but that doesn't really change anything - you're still fitting the sections of the template to the sections of your skeleton.

Here's something I put together *really* quickly, just to illustrate how to go about slicing the image. I wouldn't use my exact example, but it should point you in the right direction:

That's probably the best advice I can give with the provided information. I'll expand on my answer if you provide more details.

**EDIT**

Looking at the source on your page, it looks like you just need to float `div#middle` so the right sidebar doesn't drop below it.

CSS table layouts are really good for this kind of stuff. Give something like this a shot:

```
<style type="text/css">  
#container {   
    display:table;   
    border-collapse:collapse;   
}        
#layout {   
    display:table-row;   
}          
#left-sidebar, #right-sidebar, #content {   
    text-align:left;
    display:table-cell;   
}          
</style>  

<div id="container">   
    <div id="layout">   
        <div id="left-sidebar">   
            <!-- left sidebar-->
        </div>   
        <div id="content">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div id="right-sidebar">   
            <!-- right sidebar -->   
        </div>   
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here are some articles discussing table-based layouts in CSS2:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/table-based-layout-is-the-next-big-thing/
- http://thinkvitamin.com/design/tables-the-next-evolution-in-css-layout/

Comment: I have the psd. I'm not a good slicer. To be honest with the layout I love it but its a little difficult to figure out what what would be best to do.

Comment: http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/images/wrestling.jpg  Here's the psd jpg

Comment: Kind of stuck here. Ideas after looking at my image I posted above.

Comment: I posted an example to get you going. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the image sliced already and trying to come up with the xhtml/css code as described in my post. I have it started but not sure if I need to expand my width or what. kansasoutlawwrestling.com

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got so far?

Comment: I'm struggling with how it looks so far. From my screen its not looking good.

Comment: For example the right sidebar is pushdown which it shouldn't be.  Maybe we are looking at two different screen sizes.

Comment: I did a float left and it didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the right sidebar should also be floated left.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4556/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-james-johnson)

Comment: Something isn't right here. Not looking right to me.

Comment: I really think you should use my suggestion above. It works very well.

Comment: Not big on anything table related unless its for actual displaying data.

Comment: It's not using tables. It's using the CSS2 display property, and it's intended to replace the need for floating divs.

Comment: Tables != CSS tables. You'd do well to remember that.

Comment: What's there to be confused about? You don't have to use it... it's just a nice alternative to floating and an emerging layout technique. At the end of the day, it's still 100% css, so you're in good shape. The biggest drawback to traditional tables is that they're slow to render, but that's moot here.

Comment: Minus the css does my html look good so far?

Comment: Yea, it looks like you're off to a good start. Just keep using good practices, and keep the stylesheets updated for consistency between pages.

Comment: hmm ok now the part that is going to bother me. getting my divs aligned correctly.